# Replacing column values with maximum by group

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Say I want to locate the maximum values in one column based on the value of another (i.e. max by group). I found a number of helpful threads on how to do this ([ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868661/max-values-for-each-value-in-another-column) [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/how-to-extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-data-frame)). For example, using the plyr package,

```
ddply(data, .(x), summarise, max.score=max(y))
```

returns a list of the maximum values of y for each x.

However, what if I then wanted to replace all elements in x < max(y) with max(y) itself? (The specific application would be to recode all dates in a particular set with that set's end date.)

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: akrun's solution worked perfectly. I ended up with

```
data$y <- with(data, ave(y, x, FUN=function(f) max(f, na.rm=T)))
```

Comment: Using `library(dplyr)`, try `data %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y=max(y))`. Also, `ddply` is from `plyr` not `dplyr`.

Comment: Or in base R, `data$y <- with(data, ave(y, x, FUN = max))`

Comment: I was having trouble with NAs in the data but realized I could pass a custom function FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=T) to replace them with the max as well.

Comment: I think @aichao should post their comment as an answer, since it works (and is what I would have suggested as well).