# Replace data frame values by group using data from another data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing threshold values for different data types:

```
threshold <- c(5, 10)
type <- c("type1", "type2")
threshold.df <- data.frame(type, threshold)
```

This gives:

```
> threshold.df
   type threshold
1 type1         5
2 type2        10
```

In another data frame, I have:

```
x <- rep(1:30, 2)
y <- x^2
type <- rep(c("type1", "type2"), each = 30)
my.df <- data.frame(x, y, type)
```

Which gives:

```
> head(my.df)
  x  y  type
1 1  1 type1
2 2  4 type1
3 3  9 type1
4 4 16 type1
5 5 25 type1
6 6 36 type1
```

Now, I want to replace all y values of type 1 where x is lower that the threshold by 0.

Using dplyr, I was thinking about something like `my.df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(y = somefunction)`.

But then I'm stuck for the function implementation.

I know it can also be done using [ave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623429/replacing-column-values-with-maximum-by-group) function, but end up with the same problem.

I would know how to do it with a loop, but I'm sure there are better ways with R.

Comment: What does "all values of type 1" mean? X values? Rows?

Comment: Does this: `my.df[type == 'type1' & my.df$x < threshold.df$threshold[threshold.df$type == 'type1'], ]` OR `my.df$x[type == 'type1' & my.df$x < threshold.df$threshold[threshold.df$type == 'type1']]` give you what you want?

Comment: it's all y values where x < threshold. I edited the question

Comment: Your solution works for type1, but then I need to repeat for type2. If I have a lot of types, I wish I could automate it.

Comment: Your question says you only want to do it for 'type 1' where x is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `dplyr`:

```
my.df %>%
  inner_join(., threshold.df) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(x < threshold & type == 'type1', 0, y)) %>%
  select(-threshold)
```

Result is something like this:

```
    x   y  type
1   1   0 type1
2   2   0 type1
3   3   0 type1
4   4   0 type1
5   5  25 type1
6   6  36 type1
7   7  49 type1
8   8  64 type1
9   9  81 type1
10 10 100 type1
11 11 121 type1
12 12 144 type1
```

If you want the threshold check to apply to all types and not just type1, you can do this:

```
my.df %>%
  inner_join(., threshold.df) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(x < threshold, 0, y)) %>%
  select(-threshold)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just merge the data.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(threshold.df)
setDT(my.df)
my.df <- merge(my.df, threshold.df, by = 'type')
my.df[y < threshold, y := 0]
my.df[, threshold := NULL]
```

Comment: Alternatively by chain `my.df[threshold.df, on = .(type)][y < threshold, y := 0][, threshold := NULL]`